# Android Resources alternative for File.length()?

Tags: android, file, resources, io, inputstream

The following code (not really written by me) is used to write data of a wav file through an inputStream to android's `AudioTrack` (unimportant for my question...)

```
int bytesread = 0, ret = 0;
int size = (int) file.length();
at.play();
while (bytesread < size) {
    ret = in.read(byteData, 0, count);
    if (ret != -1) { // Write the byte array to the track
        at.write(byteData, 0, ret);
        bytesread += ret;
    }
}
```

If you use java's `File` class, you can use `File.length()` to check the file's size and see when to stop streaming/playing. However I have stored my audiofiles in the android `Resources (R.raw.example)` and to open it I use  :

```
 in = mResources.openRawResource(ResId);
```

which gives me an `InputStream`. This makes me unable to use anything similar to `File.length()` and therefore I don't know when the file has been played.

Does anyone know how to achieve something similar as the first example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [openRawResourceFd](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResourceFd%28int%29). It should return an [AssetFileDescriptor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html), which has a .getLength() method.